# How to dynamically adjust View position in onResume (Android / Java)

Tags: java, android, onresume

I am attempting move a Button around in an Android app I'm making (Java). Under certain circumstances in onResume(), I get margin information about the button, then attempt to place the button at the left edge of the screen with that margin as a slight gap so it looks nice. See below.

`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams(); button.setX(lp.leftMargin);`

However, apparently the information in my xml layout file gets read AFTER I programmatically set the button position. So, my button is getting placed exactly in the middle of the screen (as stated in xml file) PLUS 8 dp to the right. I need a way to reorder these positioning commands -- Anyone know how to queue up a dynamic view placement in onResume so it delays just enough to occur immediately after the button is done being placed by my layout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!! I guess it was a duplicate question, I couldn't find it searching before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/14116101